# Is there any chance to connect our local database which was in our laptop to aws EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm developing a react native Android application for backend I'm using spring boot framework, i hosted my endpoints in aws ec2 instance, for database I have used RDS(postgres) which costs high price so, I want an alternative to do this task, in my mind I have a thought that to connect my local database which was in my laptop/pc to aws EC2 instance. Is this possible, if possible how can I achieve it.

I know this is a stupid question for some people. But please help me.

Thanks in advance.

I want to connect my local database to aws EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes, you need to configure your AWS EC2 instance to be able to connect outbound to your database and for your local database to be fully public. Google and let us know if you face any specific issues.

Comment: Why not run Postgres on the EC2 instance?

Comment: As a student it's hard to pay the aws bill, I'm working with large size of data.